# General htaccess for .dev TLD & localhost/example with PHP routing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

I've recently setup an .dev TLD for my development work here on my local machine. But have always worked with localhost/example for my development. Because I use "http://my.ip/example" to show and test work on different machines, I would love to still keep have that working properly.

Now I've ran into the following problem:

example.dev points to localhost/example, which works fine. Although I seem to need 1 difference in my htaccess to have it working alright.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Works for the .dev TLD. While

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

(Notice the missing slash before index.php) is required to keep it working on localhost/example (because the prepended / makes it look in localhost).

Does anyone have any idea on how I could make my .htaccess or script general enough that it would work in both cases?

**Update**: Full htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATE 2**: Error log from Apache.

```
[Mon Oct 22 12:50:46 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Should work fine under `/` as well as under `/example/`, though I'm not sure how your rules weren't looping before. You'd need something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Well I have that. I have added the full htaccess in the full post. When I remove the / before index.php/$1, I get the looping error when I goto example.dev. The localhost/example version works fine at that point though. So I'll need to figure out something that works all the time...

Comment: No it exists; but it points to localhost/example/index.php - so when you use the /index.php variant, it actually points to localhost/index.php; which doesn't exist (and shouldn't exist).

Comment: @BjornSchijff What do you mean by `http://example.dev/index.php` "points to" `http://localhost/example/index.php`? Is this a redirect? Is example.dev's document root point to /example?

Comment: Well, .dev is a vhost of my Apache. It's "DocumentAlias" is set to /Development/$1. In other words, the vhost server localhost/example as example.dev. It has some perks whereas the site in development responds like it would when it is in production. But I cannot use example.dev to show and test it on other machines, because it's a local vhost.

Comment: @BjornSchijff Still not clear how you have it all setup, but as a random gues, you can try including a `RewriteBase /example/` above your rule.

Comment: I think that might work for localhost/example - but since the vhost is "aliased" to localhost/example, my guess is that it would than alias it to just localhost. I've tested it now and it worked as I expected. Maybe the errorlog will help you understand what happens. I've added it to the OP. As you can understand, the error simply acknowledges that it cannot find the right file thus keeps rewriting it and ending in an Internal error.